# How to set an IAM user to have specific rights in Kubernetes Cluster on AWS.

Tags: kubernetes, rbac, amazon-eks

I want to allow a user to do things in the Kubernetes cluster for EKS for example: apply deployment, create secrets, create volumes etc. 
I'm not sure which role to use for that. I don't want to allow users:
to create clusters, delete clusters, list cluster only perform the Kubernetes operations within the cluster.

As far as I know the permissions to the cluster are performed with Heptio authenticator. I believe I am missing something here but can't figure out what.

Comment: You can have a look at this article about how a custom operator handles EKS RBAC using IAM https://medium.com/@bhattaji00/managing-amazon-eks-rbac-using-custom-k8s-operator-5ba3ed17022

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html) is the right one to add an AWS IAM user or AWS Role to a given K8S Role.

Let's say that you wanted to create a new K8S Role to only have read permission, called ***pod-reader***

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: pod-reader
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
```

After creating the role, you need to give the permission to your IAM user to assume that role. This is easily doable doing:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: aws-auth
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  mapUsers: |
    - userarn: arn:aws:iam::270870090353:user/franziska_adler
      username: iam_user_name
      groups:
        - pod-reader
```

More information about K8S RBAC Authorization [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to manually add the users in the config map under the 'mapUsers' item and then run `kubectl apply config-map.yml` according the aws documentation in section 3. "Add your IAM users, roles, or AWS accounts to the configMap."

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/add-user-role.html